# Any tool recommendation for WCAG 2.0 validation?

Tags: accessibility, w3c, wcag

I believe everyone now a days is working hard to make web pages WCAG 2.0 compliant. Can you share any good tool for the same that you have come across?

Here are some good tools that I came across-

1.
*http://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/index.htm*

**Advantages:**

```
1. It does WCAG 2.0, WCAG 1.0, browser compatibility and many other checks
2. Low cost
```

**Disadvantage:**

```
1. it seems it doesn't have command line API.(as per my initial evaluation)
2. Web mode doesn't support HTML upload
```

2.
*http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php*

**Advantages:**

1. Free!!!
2. Supports WCAG 2.0
3. Has web service API

**Disadvantages:**

1. Web service API doesn't support HTML file upload. It expects that the HTML file is deployed somewhere on web

Comment: "I believe everyone now a days is working hard to make web pages WCAG 2.0 compliant." everyone? have you used any of the websites out there lately?

Comment: Is it not? ok,then read it as "everyone should be working hard"...

Comment: You can try Mauve Accessibility validator ( http://hiis.isti.cnr.it:8080/MauveWeb/  ). 

Advantages:

1) Free
2) Supports WCAG 2.0 (and Stanca act).
3) Support validation throught URL, HTML file upload and direct html input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used to work for a company that produces a free Chrome and Firefox extension that tests against accessibility standards including WCAG 2.0, based on an open source accessibility testing library.

Slightly nervous as this might be viewed as promotion but I don't work there any more.  I will delete this answer if this is frowned upon.

[Axe Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd?hl=en-US)

[Axe Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/axe-devtools/)

[axe-core Github Repository](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core)

Comment: This addon looks good. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No problem.  Let them know if you have any criticism or comment.  Surprised no other answers to the question.  Feel free to reward the answer with accepting it - i'm working on my reputation :-)

Comment: Looks like @Wooble is right.. Not many people are working on WCAG compliance

Comment: What does "free" mean? Is this plugin open source and GPL, or?

Comment: @Leo - no free does not imply open source at all, it is a copyrighted, commercial product. It is freely downloadable and usable as a stand alone tool - we sell a server product associated with it, which acts as a issue management tool, and can also be used to spider large websites for accessibility issues.  The license agreement for the browser extension is available on the website, if it doesn't suit your needs for an open source tool then fair enough.

Comment: Ok, thanks @iandotkelly. Yes, I prefer an open source tool. It gives me the ability to enhance it.

Comment: @Leo - they now do an open source tool called axe-core .... github.com/dequelabs/axe-core